# How do you disable or speed up the character/emoji keyboard animation?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, emoji, animation

**Context**: By default on macOS, you can press `cmd + control + space` to bring up the character keyboard (more commonly known as the emoji keyboard). Before the keyboard pops up, there is a short delay and a fade in animation. For documents where you enter such characters frequently, the delay is substantial and interferes with the flow of typing.

**The Question**: How can you speed up the time it takes to show the emoji keyboard? Is there a terminal command to disable the animation, or otherwise reduce the time it takes to ultimately enter the desired character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer -- though this will also affect other animations:

```
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
```

Comment: I was not able to read this default before setting it (macOS Monterey 12.4) but setting it seems to have helped. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: definitely helped, also removes the delay between picking and inserting an emoji